# How to inherit or create an extended version of Token-2022? "is" in Solidity

Tags: spl-token, token, token-2022

I know how to create a token **based on** Token-2022 -- instanciate it. That what in Solidity is `is` keyword.

However,  I'm confused: how to create a one that **extends** it? That is, there would be `Token-2022-Ex1` with a few additional functions and fieds in it. So that *others* will be able to instanciate `Token-2022-Ex1` as they normally would `Token-2022` for themselves.

How?